# Suspending all threads when using GifTextView on AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use `GifTextView` for my animation. This `AsyncTask` actually works but it takes so long when I use `GifTextView`. If `GifTextView` is removed from this code, `AsyncTask` works fast.

```
public class PDFCreate extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                +"/TEST/PDF/"+Ex_date+".pdf";
        try {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/TEST/PDF");
                myDir.mkdirs();

                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

                document.open();
                addMetaData(document,"LEAKS");
                addTitlePage(document,Ex_title);
                document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            FILE = "Error Create Document";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            FILE = "Cannot Create Document Path";
        }
        return FILE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        GifTextView git = (GifTextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_gift);
        git.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String st) {
        super.onPostExecute(st);
        git.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
        alert.showDialog(detail.this,"File have been saved on : \n" + st);
    }
}
```

My Question is, how to use `GifTextView` without slowing down my program?

Comment: Try to use Contructor for AsyncTask class and put the code of some object intialization and remove from preexecute and doinbackground methods and try again and let me know

Comment: Clearify yourself a bit more.

Comment: @EthicsDev can u give me example about  constructor? Actually i confuse. About what u say. Becouse GifTextView just show. Not work anything.

Comment: Go this Link : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/97b8a90702c3858db203502670c9dd9e
And check that i put some code in contructor for some intialization.
Let me know is it help for you. @AKCode

Comment: @EthicsDev It's still same. On log cat still show "Suspending all threads took" and get result so long. If i change with Textview. Time to get result not long. it make me confuse. Actually GifTextView just animation for loading.

Comment: @AKCode Okay let me check with GifTextView can you please give me exact library name that used as GifTextView

Comment: @EthicsDev compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'

Comment: @EthicsDev  I had try simply AsyncTask animation with GifTextView. Visible and gone. I had try put visible on preexecute. And gone on  onPostExecute(). But why time is still same, so long.

Comment: I am not getting  why you put visible in Preexecute and gone in onPostExecute that means you cant see GifTextView  why so that @AKCode

Comment: @EthicsDev i try to make loading animation using GIF.

Comment: @AKCode But as you put visiblity gone in postexecute how you show a GifTextView

Comment: @EthicsDev i have replaced GifTextView with Glide. It make little fast than before. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @AKCode hmm thats good Post your answer here

Answer (score 1):

EthicsDev ok thanks broh. Finally i use Glide to make faster my AsyncTask. Remove `GifTextView`
with

```
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_gift);
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
        Glide.with(leaks_detail.this).load(R.drawable.loading).override(200,200)
                .into(imageViewTarget);
```